# extracting certain size data from column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in MS SQL Server 2016.  the table has a column called notes varchar(255)
The data that contains in the notes column contains notes entry by end user.

Select ServiceDate, notes from my_table

```
ServiceDate, notes
--------------------------------------
9/1/2022     The order was called in AB13456736
9/1/2022     AB45876453 not setup
9/2/2022     Signature for AB764538334
9/2/2022     Contact for A0943847432
9/3/2022     Hold off on AB73645298
9/5/2022     ** Confirmed AB88988476
9/6/2022     /AB9847654 completed
```

I would like to be able to extract the word AB% from the notes column. I know the ABxxxxxxx is always 10 characters.  Because the ABxxxxxx always entered in different position, it's difficult to use exact extract where to look for.  I have tried substring(), left() functions and because the value AB% is always in different positions, I can't get it to extract.  is there a method I can use to do this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `PATINDEX` to find the start of the pattern, then use `SUBSTRING(,10)` to extract that part

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there is only ONE `AB{string}` in `notes`, otherwise you would need  a Table-Valued Function.

Note the nullif().  This is essentially a Fail-Safe if the string does not exist.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ServiceDate] varchar(50),[notes] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('9/1/2022','The order was called in AB13456736')
,('9/1/2022','AB45876453 not setup')
,('9/2/2022','Signature for AB764538334')
,('9/2/2022','Contact for A0943847432')
,('9/3/2022','Hold off on AB73645298')
,('9/5/2022','** Confirmed AB88988476')
,('9/6/2022','/AB9847654 completed')
 
Select *
      ,ABValue = substring(notes,nullif(patindex('%AB[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',notes),0),10)
 from @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
ServiceDate notes                               ABValue
9/1/2022    The order was called in AB13456736  AB13456736
9/1/2022    AB45876453 not setup                AB45876453
9/2/2022    Signature for AB764538334           AB76453833
9/2/2022    Contact for A0943847432             NULL
9/3/2022    Hold off on AB73645298              AB73645298
9/5/2022    ** Confirmed AB88988476             AB88988476
9/6/2022    /AB9847654 completed                NULL
```

Comment: Good one for remembering `NULLIF`